# AWS Lambda Node 18: fetch is not defined, please fix or add global fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to call the Pagespeed Insights API from an AWS Lambda to get back the results.
The lambda is running Node 18 but still unable to get `fetch()` to work.

It will show "inside the try about to fetch" in Cloudwatch but nothing after.

In my Lambda console, there is a warning that says `fetch is not defined, please fix or add global fetch`. My timeout is 2 minutes and the API call only takes a max 20 second to return a response in the browser.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Code**:

```
try {
        console.log("inside the try about to fetch", url)
        const response = await fetch(url);
        console.log("response", response)
        const contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
        console.log("response content type", contentType)
        if (!contentType || !contentType.includes("application/json")) {
          throw new TypeError("Oops, we haven't got JSON!");
        }
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        console.log("json data response", jsonData)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        return
      }
```

Comment: I encountered the error in the Lambda console but it should still work as long as you are using Node 18.x.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and adding global fetch to the lambda solved the problem.
Simply add this line to the top of your js file where you're using fetch

```
/* global fetch */
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go its similar to the code I use modeled with your sample code.

```
exports const handler = async (event) {
try {
    const response = await fetch(url);

    if (!response.ok) {
        new Error(`Oops we haven't got JSON: ${response.status}`);
    }

    const jsonData = await response.json();
    console.log('json data response', jsonData);

} catch (error) {
    console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
}
```

}