# AWS pre-signup lambda function - ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

In my NextJS v14 project I would like to create a Dynamo db record every time a user signs up. So, I followed [this official AWS tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ti0Nc_FHZLo), but I stumbled upon few hiccups, like:

1. When I run `amplify update function` in order to allow the `Mutation` operation to my function, at the end, I only get:

   ```
   You can access the following resource attributes as environment variables from your Lambda function:
    API_<MY_API_NAME>_GRAPHQLAPIENDPOINTOUTPUT
    API_<MY_API_NAME>_GRAPHQLAPIIDOUTPUT
   ```

   Meanwhile I would expect to also get `API_<MY_API_NAME>_GRAPHQLAPIKEYOUTPUT` to use it later in my lambda function (like shown in the guide)
2. Now, here's my `custom.js` file:

   ```js
   const GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT = process.env.API_<MY_API_NAME>_GRAPHQLAPIENDPOINTOUTPUT;
   const GRAPHQL_API_KEY = process.env.API_<MY_API_NAME>_GRAPHQLAPIIDOUTPUT;

   const query = /* GraphQL */ `
       mutation CREATE_USER($input: CreateUserInput!) {
           createUser(input: $input) {
               username
               email
               mobilePhoneNumber
           }
       }
   `;

   /**
    * @type {import('@types/aws-lambda').APIGatewayProxyHandler}
    */
   export const handler = async (event, context) => {
       const variables = {
           input: {
               username: event.userName,
               email: event.request.userAttributes.email,
               mobilePhoneNumber: event.request.userAttributes.phone_number,
           },
       };

       const options = {
           method: "POST",
           headers: {
               "x-api-key": GRAPHQL_API_KEY,
               "Content-Type": "application/json",
           },
           body: JSON.stringify({ query, variables }),
       };

       const response = {};

       try {
           const res = await fetch(GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT, options);
           response.data = await res.json();
           if (response.data.errors) response.statusCode = 400;
       } catch (error) {
           response.statusCode = 400;
           response.body = {
               errors: [
                   {
                       message: error.message,
                       stack: error.stack,
                   },
               ],
           };
       }

       return {
           ...response,
           body: JSON.stringify(response.body),
       };
   };
   ```

   The only difference from the tutorial is that I'm not using the `node-fetch` module, but rather the *native* fetch function since I'm using Node v18 (like suggested in [this official AWS Amplify documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/nextjs/build-a-backend/functions/set-up-function/#:%7E:text=When%20the%20Node,fetch) and confirmed by the line `"Runtime": "nodejs18.x"` inside the `/amplify/backend/function/<my_function_name>/...-cloudformation-template.json`)

   But when this lambda function gets called, I get this error:

   ```
   {
       "errorType": "ReferenceError",
       "errorMessage": "require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead\nThis file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/var/task/package.json' contains \"type\": \"module\". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension."
   }
   ```

   Now, as you saw, I'm not using any `require` import, but I discovered that the ***auto-generated*** `index.js` file (inside: `/amplify/backend/function/<my_function_name>/src/index.js`) has this line:

   ```js
   /**
   * The array of imported modules.
   */
   const modules = moduleNames.map((name) => require(`./${name}`));
   ```

   And I'm not quite sure - also because I'm kinda new to AWS - if I'm allowed to manually edit this file in order to make it ESM compatible or not.

Just for completeness, here's my `package.json` of the lambda function:

```js
{
    "name": "...",
    "type": "module",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "description": "Lambda function generated by Amplify",
    "main": "index.js",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.92"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `"type": "module"` from the package.json?

Comment: @grekier Ok, I've tried as you suggested (basically using CommonJS) and I had to make a few other changes, such as: 1) adding `/* global fetch */` on top of the `custom.js` file in order to "fix" [this fetch error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76273104/aws-lambda-node-18-fetch-is-not-defined-please-fix-or-add-global-fetch) 2) rollback by changing `export const handler` to `exports.handler`. Now, I have only one error left, `UnauthorizedException: You are not authorized to make this call` and I feel it's due to the fact that I've used `GRAPHQLAPIIDOUTPUT` insted of `GRAPHQLAPIKEYOUTPUT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to collect all the info on how to resolve these problems in case someone else is facing the same issues.

---

1. To resolve the first problem, i.e. not able to generate the `API_<MY_API_NAME>_GRAPHQLAPIKEYOUTPUT`, you just need to have the *API key* enabled as auth mode on the GraophQL API, basically run `amplify update api` and picked these options:

   ```
   ...
   ? Choose the default authorization type for the API: Amazon Cognito User Pool
   ? Configure additional auth types? Yes
   ? Choose the additional authorization types you want to configure for the API: API key
   ...
   ```

   Then re-run `amplify update function` and you will have also the `GRAPHQLAPIKEYOUTPUT`
2. For the second problem, as suggested here, I've change the lambda function to use *CommonJS* by simply removing the `"type": "module"` (inside the `package.json` file). On top of that I've also updated the function as such:

   ```js
   /* global fetch */

   // ...

   exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
       // ...
   }
   ```

   Just to clarify, the first comment - i.e. `/* global fetch */` - is needed in order to not get this fetch error: [`fetch is not defined, please fix or add global fetch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76273104/aws-lambda-node-18-fetch-is-not-defined-please-fix-or-add-global-fetch)

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json` change `"type": "module",` to `"type": "commonjs",`